# How to define constructor ?Where?

Tags: yii

- How to define constructor in Yii application?
- Where ?to define the constructors?

I need to create constructors. Where it defines inside model or controller.
Can you guys give some example of formats ?

Comment: There is a init() function you can use in models / controllers which will be executed on class call.

Comment: Yii's constructor call init() ??

Answer (score 2):

In a lot of Yii classes there are 2 methods that can be used to define initialization code : `__construct()` and `init()`:

`__construct()` is a native php method to instantiate the object.

`init()` is called when Yii has performed it's own instantiation of the class (for example in a CActiveRecord class Yii has set the scenario name)

it's up to you to use

```
public function __construct()
{
    //Your code
    return parent::contruct()
}
```

or just to use the init method

```
public function init()
{
    //Your code
}
```

if you use construct be carefull because some classes constructors have some params that you'll also have to set (for example `CActiveRecord` take the scenario name as a param)

If I were you I'll use the `init` method as often as possible.